# group_by array of hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a Ruby array of hashes that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    :account_id=>52,
    :amount_credit=>0.0,
    :amount_debit=>#<BigDecimal:7ff3f6f51c88,'0.1316837E7',9(18)>
  },
  {
    :account_id=>57,
    :amount_credit=>0.0,
    :amount_debit=>#<BigDecimal:7ff3f8157590,'0.0',9(18)>
  },
  ...
]
```

I'm trying to group this by `account_id` if there are multiple entries with the same `account_id`. I will group them and check the debit and credit if debit is higher than credit then debit - credit and put the amount in the debit vise versa of credit.

another scenario

```
final_entries = []

entries = # the first entry that I put on the top

entries.group_by {|a| a[:account_id]}.each do |contents|
    if contents.length > 1

      get_id = []
      get_debit = []
      get_credit = []
      contents.each do |subject|
        get_id << subject.account_id
        get_debit << subject.amount_debit unless subject.amount_debit == 0
        get_credit << subject.amount_credit unless subject.amount_credit == 0
        if get_debit.sum > get_credit.sum
          total = get_debit.sum - get_credit.sum
          final_entries << { account_id: get_id[0], amount_credit: 0.0, amount_debit: total }
        else
          total = get_credit.sum - get_debit.sum
          final_entries << { account_id: get_id[0], amount_credit: total, amount_debit: 0.0 }
        end
      end
    else
      final_entries << contents
    end
  end
```

> error NoMethodError: undefined method `account_id' for 52:Fixnum

Comment: This is not proper hash within array, why u r using `#` here?

Comment: that was big decimal

Comment: i just copy that in my console

Comment: @wiwit for your benefit, don't just copy/paste straight from console to question (or anywhere pretty much). Try to format and preview your question first.

Comment: @TamerShlash thanks bro

Comment: The last part of your question regarding credit and debit is not clear. Can you give an example of duplicate entries and how the end result would look like?

Comment: @TamerShlash the duplicate entry is the account_id example if account id is 132 and there is another account id is 132 the first 132 account id have a debit = 200, credit = 0 and tha another acount_id  132 debit = 0 , credit =100 the resule will be "acount_id: 132, debit 100, credit 0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the debit values used by Uday and came up with the following solution.

```
accounts = [{:account_id=>52, :amount_credit=>0.0, :amount_debit=>12.3434}, 
            {:account_id=>57, :amount_credit=>0.0, :amount_debit=>12.3434}, 
            {:account_id=>59, :amount_credit=>0.0, :amount_debit=>12.3434}, 
            {:account_id=>58, :amount_credit=>0.0, :amount_debit=>12.3434}, 
            {:account_id=>39, :amount_credit=>12.3434, :amount_debit=>0.0}, 
            {:account_id=>40, :amount_credit=>12.3434, :amount_debit=>0.0}, 
            {:account_id=>41, :amount_credit=>12.3434, :amount_debit=>0.0}, 
            {:account_id=>35, :amount_credit=>12.3434, :amount_debit=>0.0}, 
            {:account_id=>4, :amount_credit=>12.3434, :amount_debit=>0.0}, 
            {:account_id=>31, :amount_credit=>0.0, :amount_debit=>12.3434}, 
            {:account_id=>62, :amount_credit=>0.0, :amount_debit=>12.3434}, 
            {:account_id=>53, :amount_credit=>0.0, :amount_debit=>12.3434}, 
            {:account_id=>35, :amount_credit=>0.0, :amount_debit=>12.3434}, 
            {:account_id=>52, :amount_credit=>12.3434, :amount_debit=>0.0}, 
            {:account_id=>53, :amount_credit=>12.3434, :amount_debit=>0.0}, 
            {:account_id=>31, :amount_credit=>12.3434, :amount_debit=>0.0}, 
            {:account_id=>16, :amount_credit=>12.3434, :amount_debit=>0.0}]

accounts = accounts.group_by{|account| account[:account_id]}
                   .map {|id, records|
                      amount_credit = records.sum {|record| record[:amount_credit]}
                      amount_debit = records.sum {|record| record[:amount_debit]}
                      if amount_debit > amount_credit
                        {account_id: id,
                         amount_debit: amount_debit - amount_credit}
                      else
                        {account_id: id,
                         amount_credit: amount_credit - amount_debit}
                      end
                   }

p accounts
```

What I did here is I first grouped account hashes by their account_id and performed a map on the resulting hash to return the hashes for our new array.

I believe this is what you are looking here. Hope this helps.

The result I got for this was:

```
[{:account_id => 52,
  :amount_credit => 0.0
}, {:account_id => 57,
  :amount_debit => 12.3434
}, {:account_id => 59,
  :amount_debit => 12.3434
}, {:account_id => 58,
  :amount_debit => 12.3434
}, {:account_id => 39,
  :amount_credit => 12.3434
}, {:account_id => 40,
  :amount_credit => 12.3434
}, {:account_id => 41,
  :amount_credit => 12.3434
}, {:account_id => 35,
  :amount_credit => 0.0
}, {:account_id => 4,
  :amount_credit => 12.3434
}, {:account_id => 31,
  :amount_credit => 0.0
}, {:account_id => 62,
  :amount_debit => 12.3434
}, {:account_id => 53,
  : amount_credit => 0.0
}, {:account_id => 16,
  :amount_credit => 12.3434
}]
```

Comment: let me try this bro

Comment: they dont group bro

Comment: @wiwit What doesn't group? It's grouping perfectly for me.

Comment: my error is rollback and i dont know why i will double check this

Comment: (byebug) entries.group_by {|account| account[:account_id]}.map {|id, records|}
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]

Comment: @wiwit You will surely get that output on doing `entries.group_by {|account| account[:account_id]}.map {|id, records|}`. You haven't defined what you are going to return there for your elements.

Comment: If you want to see the result of your grouping, simply do this: `entries.group_by{|account| account[:account_id]}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164387/discussion-between-wiwit-and-nabin-paudyal).

Answer (score 1):

Let me run through your existing code:

```
entries.group_by {|a| a[:account_id]}.each do |contents|
  if contents.length > 1 # This will always be true, since contents is an Array of [account_id, [entries]]
    get_id = []
    get_debit = []
    get_credit = []
    contents.each do |subject| # Again, contents is a Hash of account_id => [entries]; should be |id, entries|
      get_id << subject.account_id  # Even if this was a single entry, this wouldn't work since it's a Hash; should be subject[:account_id]
      get_debit << subject.amount_debit unless subject.amount_debit == 0  # Fails for the same reason
      get_credit << subject.amount_credit unless subject.amount_credit == 0  # Fails for the same reason
      if get_debit.sum > get_credit.sum  # We're summing what we saved, but excluded 0 values even though they don't change the sum?
        total = get_debit.sum - get_credit.sum  # Avoid summing again
        final_entries << { account_id: get_id[0], amount_credit: 0.0, amount_debit: total }
      else
        total = get_credit.sum - get_debit.sum
        final_entries << { account_id: get_id[0], amount_credit: total, amount_debit: 0.0 }
      end
    end
  else
    final_entries << contents
  end
end
```

And now what I would do:

```
final_entries = entries
  .group_by { |entry| entry[:account_id] }
  .map do |id, acct_entries|
    return acct_entries.first if acct_entries.size == 1

    credit = acct_entries.map { |entry| entry[:amount_credit] }.sum
    debit = acct_entries.map { |entry| entry[:amount_debit] }.sum

    if credit > debit
      credit -= debit
      debit = 0.0
    else
      debit -= credit
      credit = 0.0
    end
    { account_id: id, amount_credit: credit, amount_debit: debit }
  end
```

Comment: let me try this

Comment: @wiwit Yes, see [`Array#size`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-size)

Comment: @Andrew, Wow, this is very similar to my solution. Btw, you don't need to map and then sum, you can simply pass your code block to sum.

Comment: @NabinPaudyal Not sure if you’re accusing me of something there, but it’s merely a coincidence. Yea, though I always thought that was a slightly overloaded responsibility of `sum` to have.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, I'm not accusing. Just pointing out the coincidence. There are several differences as well. Peace, mate!

Comment: @NabinPaudyal cheers :). The solution, seemingly, emerges quite naturally.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

```
res = arr.group_by { |h| h[:account_id] }.map do |key, duplicates|
  credit = duplicates.sum { |h| h[:amount_credit] || 0 }
  debit = duplicates.sum { |h| h[:amount_debit] || 0 }
  {
    account_id: key,
    amount_credit: (credit > debit ? credit - debit : 0),
    amount_debit: (debit > credit ? debit - credit : 0)
  }
end
```

Worth mentioning that [Enumerable#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0_rc1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) is only available in Ruby 2.4.0 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
final_entries = []
entries.group_by {|a| a[:account_id]}.each do |key, value|
    if value.length > 1
      get_debit = []
      get_credit = []
      value.each do |subject|
        get_debit << subject[:amount_debit] if subject[:amount_debit] > 0
        get_credit << subject[:amount_credit] if subject[:amount_credit] > 0
      end
      if get_debit.sum > get_credit.sum
        total = get_debit.sum - get_credit.sum
        final_entries << { account_id: key, amount_credit: 0.0, amount_debit: total }
      else
        total = get_credit.sum - get_debit.sum
        final_entries << { account_id: key, amount_credit: total, amount_debit: 0.0 }
      end
    else
      final_entries << value[0]
    end
  end
```